# How to make server simulate user connection to website and do some actions in js?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

Is there a way to simulate user connect to website and do some actions on website I want to be connected?

For example someone go to my website and type "website.com" and choose actions to make and then my server should connect to "website.com" and do actions like submit form, check some checkboxes etc.

How can I do such a thing? I dont even know how to search it in google.

Comment: I googled "simulate browser in php" and found: http://mink.behat.org

Comment: More general terms: GUI Testing / front-end testing / UI test automation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what I can understand you want to simulate browser actions.

I was able to build some automated jobs with **Puppeteer** for my company
(Account Logins, File Downloads, Screenshots and more).

You will need to install **NodeJS** and run on server side.
You cannot achieve this client side (your browser).

In Practice you run a "headless" version of Chrome (Chromium)
and you program every click, keyboard input, page load.

Read more here:

---

***Puppeteer***

https://pptr.dev/

> Puppeteer is a Node library which provides a high-level API
>       to control Chrome or Chromium over the DevTools Protocol. 
>       Puppeteer runs headless by default, but can be configured 
>       to run full (non-headless) Chrome or Chromium.

---

Comment: Thanks, that was something I was looking for, do you know if I could do it in simple jquery and php?

Comment: It is a NodeJS library so NO PHP.
You write Javascript  code ServerSide! 
Once you set it up and try connecting to a site, you can run Browser Javascript code ! So if the site you are trying to connect runs jquery you can use jquery . 
Check:
https://pptr.dev/#?product=Puppeteer&version=v1.19.0&show=api-pageevalselector-pagefunction-args-1

Comment: Ok, but could I do it with just js/jquery withour using node?